# GridView template Column conditionally set to readonly

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Is there a way to set a Template Column on a GridView to readonly from code behind.
Like if test for `Admin=true make readonly= false else readonly = true`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct way to set the `GridView` column to readonly. But You can set the controls to readonly that are in that column in the `RowDataBound` event of your `GridView`. e.g.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit || e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Alternate)
    {
        TextBox txt = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("ControlID");
        txt.ReadOnly = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try this I get Compiler Error Message: CS0123: No overload for 'grdProducts_RowDataBound' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Comment: replace this line with ---- protected void grdProducts_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)

Comment: I think problem when you define event handle, just copy from my answer

Comment: I think it may be more difficult, I left out I'm using BulEditGridView, event does fire but does not find control even if I change id to "ctl00_MasterBody_grdProducts_ctl02_txt0", which I do see in View Source

Comment: can you try TextBox txt = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txt0"); ?

Comment: It does fin control and set readonly but still get edit box, txt.visible does make it not display, but need it readonly

Comment: @BillTetrault Thank You! I wasn't given the readonly option, but `.Enabled = false;` works just as well for my purposes

Answer (score 5):

I find Muhammad Akhtar's answer is almost spot on except I need to change the if clause slightly in my case to cover all the conditions. My if clause is as follows.

```
if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) == DataControlRowState.Edit || 
    (e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Alternate) == DataControlRowState.Alternate)
```

I didn't find any problem with the original one until I have a special value of `e.Row.RowState` as "Alternate | Edit", which make

```
(e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit || 
 e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Alternate) == false
```

Nevertheless, I should thank Muhammad Akhtar for pointing me towards the right direction.

Here is my complete code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) == DataControlRowState.Edit || (e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Alternate) == DataControlRowState.Alternate)
   {
      TextBox txt = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("ControlID");
      txt.ReadOnly = true;
   }
}
```

PS: In order to make DropDownList readonly, you need to disable it in its OnDataBound event:

```
protected void DropDownList1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((DropDownList)sender).Enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, tap into ItemDataBound event, and for each row, either use a readonly control and an edit control and show/hide the right control for the job, or alternatively disable the edit control.  There's no global readonly setting for templates.

HTH.