# Gridview Set Column ReadOnly Programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to set some columns as ReadOnly in my GridView. As I'm using the same ASPX for several different views, I need to do this in back end code. I've seen several posts on this but not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm getting the error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Here is my code:

```
protected void FormsGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        TextBox txt = (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ID")) as TextBox;
        txt.ReadOnly = true;
    }
}
```

I have also tried the following with the same results.

```
TextBox txt = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("ID");
txt.ReadOnly = true;
```

I also tried the following and got the error `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.`

```
((BoundField)FormsGridView.Columns[1]).ReadOnly = true;
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT: GridView code added**

```
<asp:GridView ID="FormsGridView" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDS1" OnDataBound="FormsGridView_DataBound" AllowPaging="True" 
    AllowSorting="True" PageSize="1000" onprerender="GridView_PreRender" 
    CssClass="GridView" onrowcreated="FormsGridView_RowDataBound">
    <PagerSettings Position="Top" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Wrap="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="DeleteButton" runat="server">
                    <img  src="images/delete.png" alt="Delete Item" width="16px" height="16px" style="cursor:pointer;vertical-align:bottom;text-decoration:none" /></asp:HyperLink>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="EditButton" runat="server">
                    <img  src="images/edit.png" alt="Edit Item" width="16px" height="16px" style="cursor:pointer;vertical-align:bottom;text-decoration:none" /></asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>    
    </Columns>
    <PagerTemplate>
        <div class="pages">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="PagingDropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="PagingDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged" height="30px" />
        </div>
    </PagerTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

UpdateCommand is also being done on the back end:

```
FormsGridView.AutoGenerateEditButton = true;
SqlDS1.UpdateCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlDS1.UpdateCommand = ("SP");
```

What seems odd to me is that I can pull the values from cells using the following:

```
id = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ID"));
```

But when attempting to reference as a TextBox is when I get the `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error.

```
TextBox txt = (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ID")) as TextBox;
txt.ReadOnly = true;
```

Just for kicks, I changed the name "ID" to "SomeID" which is not returned by the stored procedure and I do in fact get a different error as expected `DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'SomeID'.`

Comment: Please post your GridView markup.

Comment: Based on your error, it clearly isn't finding your Control `Id`.  Your syntax looks valid, but we will need to see your Grid syntax.

Comment: @Greg added GridView as requested

Comment: @doby48 Where is your `Id` Control / Textbox, I don't see it in your code.

Comment: @Greg I don't have the textbox in my ASPX, I'm using AutoGenerateColumns which it looks like is the problem here. I found a solution going a different route to set some columns to ReadOnly and added it as an Answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

As I wasn't able to set AutoGenerateColumns="False" I was unable to set the columns to ReadOnly as I was attempting to do. So what I ended up doing was adding DataKeyNames in the code behind instead, for each of the columns I needed to be ReadOnly. So my code is like this:

```
FormsGridView.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "ID", "Name" };
```

I also moved this further up in my code where I assign some variables as I was receiving an error `Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList` if I assigned the DataKeyNames after my PageNumbers DropDownList which is created in the FormsGridView_DataBound function.

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving the error because you are returning a null TextBox object and then trying to set it to read-only.

The TextBox controls won't be in the GridView unless you are in Edit Mode, so you need to check if the RowState is Edit. Note: The `if` statement may need adjusting based on your GridView definition.

```
if (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit ||
    e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Alternate)
{
    TextBox txt = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("ID");
    txt.ReadOnly = true;
}
```

You can also reference this question: [GridView template Column conditionally set to readonly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897985/gridview-template-column-conditionally-set-to-readonly)

**UPDATE**
You need to set AutoGenerateColumns = FALSE and define your columns.
Look at this post: [Allowing one column to be edited but not another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654242/allowing-one-column-to-be-edited-but-not-another)

Comment: I saw that post and had tried that with no success. I also tried the code you provided and I'm still receiving the same error.

Comment: Edited original post to include GridView as requested.

Comment: I see the GridView markup now.  Where is the TextBox, I don't see it?